# Python 2.7- how to save a picture through tuple or set values?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, python-imaging-library

So I've been using opencv2 and PIL to get pixel values. They're saved as such

(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)

I've tried like 7 different ways to use this data to create an image.

My biggest problem is I can't seem to get putdata to work with my tuple.

I would show code, but my laptop is flat and my code is broken anyway.

Tldr: how to save an image with PIL using pixel values stored in a tuple?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
from PIL import Image

W = 200
H = 200
img = Image.new("RGB", (W, H))

pixel_list = [(i%256,i%256,i%256) for i in range(W*H)]
i_pixel = 0
for x in range(W):
    for y in range(H):
        img.putpixel((x, y), pixel_list[i_pixel])
        i_pixel += 1

img.save('result.png')
```

With the following result

[image: Result of the code above]

Note: I read [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) the following:

In 1.1.6, the above is better written as:

```
pix = im.load()
for i in range(n):
    ...
    pix[x, y] = value
```

But I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: So where do I put my tuple/ set? (its called z_set). Do I replace I_pixel with z_Set?

Comment: `pixel_list` is a list of tuples with the pixels. I think this is called `z_Set` for you, so you use `z_Set[i_pixel]`.

Comment: That did not work for me. What did work was [img.putpixel((index, 0), value) for index, value in enumerate(z_set)

Comment: If you have only one loop and point to the pixel to change with `(index, 0)`, then you are only changing the first column of the image and you end up with a one-dimensional image. If that was your intention, it was not clear from your original problem description.